# Close tableview in ViewBasedApplication

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, navigation, tableview, transition

probably a very simple question but can't find the right answer anywhere. I am using XCode 4 and working on an iphone app, which probably sums up all the info that I need to provide.

Here it is:
- I created a ViewBasedApplication
- At some point depending on the user input, I load a TableView

But now how on Earth do I add a button or something to return?  Note: I can't use a NavigationBased app, that would be easier but would not work for me.

Help anyone?

Comment: What do you mean by return? Remove the tableview?

Comment: Without knowing much about your app, you could present the tableView modally and then have an action set on a button to trigger a method in your code that dismisses the modal view.

Comment: "I am using XCode 4 and working on an iphone app, which probably sums up all the info that I need to provide." Not so much. There are a lot of ways to add a UITableView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used a `UITableViewController`, you may want to use a `UIViewController` instead. In the `UIVeiwController`, you can add a UITableView along with your own `UINavigationBar` or, if you don't want to use a `UINavigationBar`, you could leave room for some type of custom `UIButton`. Either the `UINavigationBar` button or your custom `UIButton` action could trigger a close of your `UIViewController`.

If you add the UIViewController as a subview, then Cyprian's `[self removeFromSuperView];` would work. If you present as a modal as Jamie suggests, you could use `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to do it.

Comment: **dismissModalViewControllerAnimated is deprecated**. You should use `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know you code but you could always call

[self removeFromSuperView];

Comment: Nick: by remove I mean I want to close the current uitableview and return to the view that invoked the tableview. I added it as a subview, like this: [self.view addSubview:pavasViewController.view];. So yes, removefromsuperview would work but I don't know how to add a button or something to invoke this action.  Thoughts anyone? Thanks for the help in advance.